# Use of getfilter search in Custom listview Listadapter

Tags: android, listview

I have created a custom listview fetching data from webservices.Now i need to put a search filter using EditText and i did it too but it shows me error that to create getFilter() in ListAdapter method.

```
lstVendor.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

         /**
         * Enabling Search Filter
         * */
        inputSearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

             public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
              }

              public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
              }

              public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
               VendorListByCategoryActivity.this.vendorAdapterList.getFilter().filter(s.toString());//got error
              }

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change **ListAdapter** to **SimpleAdapter** and keep everything same... 
InshaAllah, It will work...